# How to get the body element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the body element of an html using jquery and then disable the vertical scrolling?

Comment: well, body element is just $("body"). Not sure what you mean by disable vertical scrolling... you can achieve that by just having a fixed height :S

Comment: What have you tried so far and which part of that are you having problems with? I assume its the getting the body element from your title...

Comment: I don't understand why people keep closing a valid question, just because the English is not well articulated big deal, the question is still valid and should edit it or ask for more information as oppose to just close it or delete it.

Comment: You mean a fixed height in percent, right? A usual fixed height will get you into scrolling on some resolutions/screen sized (800*600, cell phones etc.)

Comment: @Val: The question shows no effort. It is clear the user has not tried anything themselves and are leaving us to do all the work for him.

Comment: @matt the question has a one line code response, it's valid, forgive him for being a beginner, as any teacher would tell you, it's better to ask a stupid question, than suffer of ignorance of not asking at all, what he asked is simple, basic, newbee and should not be treated as if he should know what he asks, else he/she would not need to be here and ask.

Comment: @Val: How about this version of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8035695/4. It shows he's tried *something* himself, but still leaves it clear that he's a beginner.

Comment: @Matt not arguing anymore lol, you know I'am right just by allowing the person to understand this way, if you close it, like you did above, he simply asked another question coz doesn't know what happened to that question, n got no help with it.

Comment: @Val: "you know I'am right"... LOL

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this...

`$('body,html').css('overflow','hidden');`

the `,html` allows you to also include the `<html>` because some browsers may use that as the base as oppose to the `<body>` tag so it helps treating both as if they were one.

**helpful**
any tag should be selected like so `$('a');` or `$('body');`

an element can be selected by `id` using the prefix `#` so

`<a id="c_1" >CLick Me</a>`

```
$('#c_1');
```

or by `class` with the prefix `.`

`<a class="classname">Click Me</a>`

```
$('.classname');
```

for more information read http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ 
as for the scroll bars they are controlled by css, you could simply go on a css file and do the following.

`body, html {overflow: hidden;}`

the `overflow` parameter allows you to control what happens when content `overflow` the assigned width and hight.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow

or the proper reference http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html

sorry if this is too technical, but one day you would have to learn about these :)

Comment: How i can enable scrolling again...?

Comment: `$('body,html').css('overflow','scroll');` or `$('body,html').css('overflow','auto');` read on the links, I sent you and investigate different values :)

Answer (score 13):

You can get the body element with: `$("body")`
then disable the scrollbars with CSS

```
 $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

Answer (score 9):

Since nobody mentioned this, it's pretty easy to select the `body` element without jQuery.

It's simply:

```
document.body;
```

And based on your question, you would disable vertical scrolling by setting `overflow: hidden`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zmpzvptL/)

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```